# Why does my type erasure crash if given a std::array

Tags: c++, crash, type-erasure, stdarray

Taken from the infamous presentation of Sean Parent, I implemented a class with type-erasure and want to initialize it with a custom struct that composites a large std::array of floats

```
class Anything 
{ 
public: 
  Anything() = default; 
  template <typename T> 
  Anything(T x) : self_(std::make_shared<model_t<T>>(std::move(x))){} 

private: 
  struct concept_t 
  { 
    virtual ~concept_t() = default; 
  }; 

  template <typename T> 
  struct model_t : concept_t 
  { 
    //    explicit model_t(T&& x) 
    //      : data_(std::forward<T>(x)) 
    explicit model_t(T x) : data_(std::move(x)){} 

    T data_; 
  }; 

public: 
  std::shared_ptr<const concept_t> self_; 
};  


class Data{ 
 std::array<float, 250000> data_; 
};
```

However, upon compilation and running the program:

```
std::vector<Anything> vec; 
vec.emplace_back(Data{});
```

I get the following:

> The program has unexpectedly finished.

If I use std::forward (commented code section) instead of std::move to sink in the constructor argument, I don't face any problems.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Same code but with forwarding

```
class Anything
{
public:
  Anything() = default;
  template <typename T>
  Anything(T&& any) 
    : self_(std::make_shared<model_t<T>>(std::forward<T>(any))){}

private: 
  struct concept_t
  {

    virtual ~concept_t() = default;
  };

  template <typename T>
  struct model_t : concept_t
  {
    explicit model_t(T&& any) : data_{ std::forward<T>(any) }{}

    T data_;
  }; 

  std::shared_ptr<const concept_t> self_;
};
```

Comment: The [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) class "is a container that encapsulates fixed size arrays". Therefore when you pass it by value you basically pass around the whole array. And for an array of 250000 `float` elements, that one million bytes. Which is dangerously close to the Windows 1MiB default stack size.

Comment: ... And `std::forward` avoids one redundant copy, so you don't overflow the stack

Comment: @StoryTeller: it is not the `std::forward` (vs the `std::move`) but `T x` vs `T&& x` which reduce number of copies.

Comment: thank you guys! So is the use of a universal reference the better solution here? After all, it decays to std::move if passed an rvalue. I wonder then, why the pass-by-value idion with subsequent move into place is so popular, when a universal reference is that much more convenient? also, I believe that the move operations of the model class are implicitly deleted due to the definition of a virtual dtor in its base class. Does that matter here?

Comment: You don't use universal reference as `T` is fixed for `model_t<T>`, you just use rvalue reference.

Comment: I added a version with perfect forwarding, my questions remain

Comment: *"I wonder then, why the pass-by-value idiom with subsequent move into place is so popular"*: pass by value idiom uses explicit type (else indeed forwarding reference is more appropriate). That allow to avoid to write several overload (`const X&` and `X&&`). it expects that types are cheap to move (which is not the case of your class `Data`).

Comment: thank you, so in this case it actually makes more sense to use the forward syntax